# How to map EC2 instance to the correct product entry from the Price List Query?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, aws-sdk-nodejs

From using the AWS-SDK, I am unsure of how to map the Instance information to the applicable product entry from the Price List Query.

I am using NodeJS @aws-sdk/client-ec2 and @aws-sdk/client-pricing.  I use the DescribeInstancesCommand to get the info on the instances.  From that information, I have RegionCode, InstanceType, ImageId, plus other details.

Now I use GetProductsCommand and it returns a list of products with prices for the right instanceType and regionCode.

The struggle I am having is now how to map the instance to what product entry applies.  How to map from Instance to the applicable product?  Is there an API that links the two entries together?

Thanks.

Comment: " I have RegionCode, InstanceType" ... "it returns a list of products with prices for the right instanceType and regionCode" ... "The struggle I am having is now how to map the instance to what product entry applies"  What exactly are you having trouble with?  You have the same data on both sides right?  Include details

Comment: I can get the list of product SKU for the InstanceType.  There is a wide variation in the prices.  For example, I pulled t2.micro and there around 20 entries.  Ideally, I would like to be able to match up the SKU that AWS uses for the Instance, but I do not see it.  I enabled the billing logging record so am going to look at the raw logs to see if AWS includes the SKU  used for the instance.